# Docker-compose links vs external_links

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, docker-compose

I believe it is simple question but I still do not get it from Docker-compose documentations. What is the difference between links and external_links?

I like external_links as I want to have core docker-compose and I want to extend it without overriding the core links.

What exactly I have, I am trying to setup logstash which depends on the elasticsearch. Elasticsearch is in the core docker-compose and the logstash is in the depending one. So I had to define the elastic search in the depended docker-compose as a reference as logstash need it as a link. BUT Elasticsearch has already its own links which I do not want to repeat them in the dependent one.

Can I do that with external_link instead of link?

I know that links will make sure that the link is up first before linking, does the external_link will do the same?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `links` when you want to link together containers within the same docker-compose.yml.  All you need to do is set the link to the service name. Like this:

```
---
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"

logstash:
  image: logstash:latest
  command: logstash -f logstash.conf
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

If you want to link a container inside of the docker-compose.yml to another container that was not included in the same docker-compose.yml or started in a different manner then you can use `external_links` and you would set the link to the container's name. Like this:

```
---
logstash:
  image: logstash:latest
  command: logstash -f logstash.conf
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  external_links:
    - my_elasticsearch_container
```

I would suggest the first way unless your use case for some reason requires that they cannot be in the same docker-compose.yml

Comment: Might be worth it to link to the official docs as well: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-links

Answer (score 0):

I think `external_link` will do not do the same as `links` in `docker-compose up` command.

`links` waits for container to boot up and get IP address which is used in `etc/hosts` file, therefore `external_link` has already IP:hostname values name described in docker-compose file.

Moreover [links will be deprecated](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/3smpwt/linking_with_link_will_be_deprecated_how_does/)

Answer (score -3):

Here is a link to Docker-Compose project that uses Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana. You will see that I'm using links:

https://github.com/bahaaldine/elasticsearch-paris-accidentology-demo