# AWS ECS nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, flask, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run a flask and nginx application on with the AWS ECS using Docker. The application The containers all run on the same docker machine. When the Task starts, the nginx container exits with exit code 1 with the following error: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:5000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
    web:
        image: 131099/generateme
        expose:
            - 5000
        networks:
            - generateme
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options: 
                awslogs-group: generateme
                awslogs-region: eu-west-2
                awslogs-stream-prefix: web
    server:
        image: 131099/generateme-server
        ports:
            - 80:80
        environment:
            - DOCKER_PROVIDER = ecs
        external_links:
            - web
        depends_on:
            - web
        networks:
            - generateme
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options: 
                awslogs-group: generateme
                awslogs-region: eu-west-2
                awslogs-stream-prefix: server
```

This is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
upstream generateme {
    server web:5000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        proxy_pass http://generateme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Any ideas what caused this? I read other similar posts but I cannot understand what to do since I am new to ECS.

Edit: when I looked at the logs it seems that the server container always starts before the web container. How can that happen if there is a depends_on property?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
external_links:
   - web
```

by

```
links:
   - web
```

More detailed answer
[Docker-compose links vs external_links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154441/docker-compose-links-vs-external-links)